# Assigning the value to an empty field

Tags: php, mysql

Need to update a field in database, but when I make a request, it writes me "0 rows affected" although the image field is, and it is empty.

```
UPDATE `oc_product` SET `image`= 'no_image.png' WHERE `image`='';
```

Comment: Do you see any records when you type  select * from oc_product WHERE `image`='';

Comment: No, I dont. Do you know whant it could be the reason?

Comment: It seems to work fine in an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f7e37/1). Are you certain the value is an empty string? If it is it should work, the value isn't an empty string like you think it is (*ex: white space, null, etc*).

Comment: It is null. See the screen please http://imgur.com/721LO1O

Comment: @Danilkalmykov `NULL` isn't equal to an empty string `''`, that's why it doesn't work. You need to check for null instead: `... WHERE \`image\` IS NULL;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is checking for a value of an empty string, although from what you have shown the value you are actually looking to change has a value of `NULL`. These are two different values, `NULL` isn't equal to `''`. As such if you are looking to replace items that have a `NULL` value you need to change your where statement for that (`WHERE image IS NULL`):

```
UPDATE `oc_product` SET `image`= 'no_image.png' WHERE `image` IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did select query returns any rows
select image from oc_product WHERE image='';

If so add other field confition as well to check whether it is getting affected ot not example

UPDATE oc_product SET image= 'no_image.png' WHERE (image= "" AND image IS NULL) and other_column ='column value';

Hope this helpful for you :)

Comment: I tried to make such a request to the database UPDATE oc_product SET image= 'no_image.png' WHERE (image= "" AND image IS NULL) but it returns 0 rows affected. With all that, I do not see  any records when you type select * from oc_product WHERE image=''';

Comment: @Danilkalmykov Then you clearly have no elements that have an empty string as a value.

Comment: if you see 0 rows returned on that select query then that update will return 0 rows.Do you see empty image records in that table and try to use other columns and check with select query .Then use that condition for update

Comment: Try UPDATE oc_product SET image= 'no_image.png' WHERE image IS NULL

Comment: Before that please try with select query to check rows that are getting effected for reference
select image from oc_product WHERE image IS NULL;